# Stopping zend route default paramaters 'key' displaying in the URL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I have a route defined as below.

```
$route['manage-vehicles'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  'vehicles/manage/page/:page',
  array(
    'controller' => 'vehicles',
    'action'     => 'manage',
    'page'       => '1'
  )
);
```

When the 'page' parameter is not specifically defined (e.g. in a menu constructed using the navigation component), the resultant URL is

/vehicles/manage/page

I would much prefer or the URL not to to display the default paramater key in this scenario

i.e. /vehicles/manage

Any ideas how to accomplish this would be appreciated?

Thanks.

EDIT: For clarity, I **would** like vehicles/manage/page/1 etc to display when the 'page' parameter is defined

Answer (score 0):

The 'page' string you have in your route is not required for the page parameter to work, so all you need to do is change your route to:

```
$route['manage-vehicles'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  'vehicles/manage/:page',
  array(
    'controller' => 'vehicles',
    'action'     => 'manage',
    'page'       => '1'
  )
);
```

you've told it which thing in the URL is 'page', so you don't need the prefix there. That's just part of the default route where the parameters are not predefined.

Comment: Tim, thanks for responding. Yes I have other routes for which I do that e.g. vehicle/update/1, but in this case I think displaying the 'key' when paginating is more friendly. For the URL vehicles/manage/2, the purpose of the 2 is obscure.